Can't run maven command in terminal - CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
on Windows:
I try to execute the next mvn command:
mvn install -DjenkinsAcceptance=true -Dcucumber.forkCount=4 -Dcucumber.test.failure.ignore=true

But rise error:
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\myuser\.sdkman\candidates\java\current\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\dev\myproject\module2\target\runtime"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:594)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec (Java13CommandLauncher.java:61)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch (DefaultExecutor.java:279)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:904)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init> (ProcessImpl.java:453)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start (ProcessImpl.java:139)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:594)


I found solution. Use <longClasspath> in Maven plugin exec-maven-plugin
In pom.xml
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <configuration>
          ...
          <longClasspath>true</classpathScope>
          ...
        </configuration>
</plugin>

